# How can I properly display standard deviation on a calc chart?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am a total newbie with this kind of operations, but I have a calc sheet with four values and I want to create a chart out of those values, showing two (indipendent) average values and their standard deviations. This is the data that I'm using.

```
  avg ratio 1/2                 avg ratio 2/1
      0.72                          1.40
standard deviation            standard deviation   
      0.67                          2.24
```

I have created a bar chart by selecting the first two rows, and it just worked.

Then I have tried to add an "error bar Y", selected standard deviation... but I can't set the values, so this is probably not the correct choice.

So I have clicked on the first bar, selected "data area", then specified the value for the first bar (A4) and the "same value for both" checkbox... it seemed to work but... if I select the second bar the deviation disappears.

Lastly, if I try to do the same directly on the second bar, the standard deviation line goes outside of the chart's margin, and I can't see its boundaries.

How can I properly create this kind of charts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a bug in Libreoffice 4.4.2.2 on Ubuntu 15.04. If I try to do the same with LibreOffice 4.2.x it seems to be correctly working.